# multiple confirmation when deleting record in rails 4 with turbolink

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am facing the problem of multiple confirmation when deleting record in rails 4 using turbolink, some says i should move my javascript_include_tag to the head which I already did but the problem still occurs. Can anyone sight what am I missing.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It asks you to confirm twice ?

Comment: @NullSoulException, yes it asked for confirmation more than once. Thanks.